# Increment record in Database

Tags: sqlite

I want to increment `Total` by one if we insert the same `Name` and `Age`. Otherwise it should be inserted as a new row with count 1.

```
id     Name       Age   Total
 1    Priyanka     23     1
```

Comment: is your id field is primary key?

Comment: Yes id is primary key

Answer (score 2):

First check if record is there

> SELECT * FROM yourTableName WHERE Name = 'your name' AND Age = your
>   age;

check if you found record from above query then

> UPDATE yourTableName SET Total = youraboverecord.total+1 WHERE ID = youraboverecord.id;

Else Simply insert your record.

Comment: Thnks for Reply Can we do from Exists Query

Comment: You can but that is only for checking if exists or not as Exists will return you 1 or 0 not record so in order to update record you have to again excuse select query so you can get id and total to update that record. In some cases this will improve efficiency as Exists will reduce the select query in case of entry not there.